# Android Network lag when switching between same SSID APs

Tags: android, wifi, lag, switching, ssid

Has anyone experienced connection lagging in Android applications when the device switches between WiFi APs with same SSID?

Our test branch have two old WiFi APs without support for Seamless Roaming. We have a simple backend with a REST API and Android clients communicating through the local WiFi network. Tested with clients running Android 5.1 and 6.0.1.

When we move the client from AP to the other, there's a 30-60s period when the network hangs and none of the Request succeed. The fun part is that it didn't produce a connection timeout.

Is there any way to make this process smooth through the client software or we should upgrade or WiFi infrastructure?

The client uses OkHttp library and communicaties over HTTPS with 10 seconds timeout for read, write and connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on when your android device decides to reassociate/reconnect to the new AP.  The android device might still be associated to the old AP until the signal strength falls below a certain threshold.  When the quality of wifi signal is not great, your requests may experience lot of errors on the wireless medium.

One way to handle this is to check for signal strength every few seconds and try reassociating to the new AP when the currently associated wifi signal strength is below a certain threshold - higher than the default.